Come open, come loose, etc. | Can "come" be used with any adjectives like this?

One of the vessels come came open and it caused a small bleed in her head.

The verb "come open" has caught my attention, because I have previously seen "come" being used with another adjective (loose) and formed to come loose. Such usage of "come" reminded me of "get" being used with such adjectives and mean "to become+adjective".
My question is: Can "come" act like "get" and work with all adjectives or is it simply restricted to some adjectives only as shown above.

I was trying to think of other examples and landed on the "come [preposition]" forms: come out, come back, come in, come forth, come around, etc., with meanings something like "to become so situated".

A situation can come good but not *come bad

You come good but go bad.

Interesting question.
I think that the adjectives it can work with form a loose semantic field that you might call UNFASTENED: come apart, come loose, come open, come adrift, come untied, come detached, come unzipped, come unbuttoned.
But not all adjectives that might be in that semantic area will work: I'm dubious about "come separated", and none of "come shattered", "come split", "come divided", "come isolated" will work. I can't see any property which will allow you to predict which ones won't work.
What is interesting to me is that this is the same semantic field as verbs traditionally formed with "un-": unlock, untie, unwrap, undo, unstrap, unwind. Outside this semantic area, verbs with un- were very very rare (the archaic "unsay" is about the only one), until the advent of computer interfaces ("untag", "undelete" etc).
(Note that I'm talking about verbs formed with un-: there's no such restruction on un- with adjectives.)

The relevant state doesn't involve an actor acting upon the thing.  Something cannot shatter itself but it can loosen or fall apart or asunder, or free itself.  At least some possibilities can be ruled out.

Mebbe, @TimR. But that doesn't account for the unacceptability of come split. And some of those can have an actor, though they don't have to have: I worked at the knot, and eventually it came undone.

UNFASTENED is too restrictive a notion. Consider come together as in This dip is delicious. And it comes together in a jiffy.

Since the intransitive verb split means "to come apart along a seam of some kind"  there's no need for come + adjective "split".  We'd just say "it split" rather than "it came split".

@PaulTanenbaum: no, that's a different use. Together is marginal as an adjective, and I don't believe it is one here. More to the point, in the examples above, once something has come X, you can say that it is X,, but it would be very odd to describe a dip as "together".

@TimR: you may be right, but that's a very weak argument. The possibility of expressing something in a simpler way isn't usually a bar to its grammaticality. Also, unzipped can also be used in the same "middle" sense, but come unzipped seems quite natural to me.

@ColinFine I think the optimality principle would stand in the way of a periphrastic construction like "come split" when simple "split" handles the present tense idea of "come apart into two pieces" and the past tense "came apart into two pieces" and the perfect,  to boot, since the past participle of "split" is also "split".  Look like "split" owns the place.

@PaulTanenbaum: I certainly wouldn't use intransitive come together like that. For me, there would have to be an agent or a passive constructive, ...and you can put it together in a jiffy, ...and it can be put together in a jiffy.

...he made his prediction and it came true.

@FumbleFingers "come together" in that context is a very common usage. Hannibal certainly loved it when it happened to his plans.

@Mohiri: I agree that came together is natural there, but, as I said, I don't think it is the construction that is being asked about.

I think what distinguishes your working examples from the ones that don't work is that one thing can come free or come alive, where the thing becomes detached from a fixed base. But a thing generally doesn't *come destroyed, and multiple things don't *come separated. A turban can come unwound, but a clock can't. Instead a clock goes dead or perhaps goes unwound. That's still not quite the full story, because “come apart” seems to be a bit of an exception.

Interesting comparison here: something can come alive, but it can't come dead. Instead, it can go dead. It suggests a biased perception from the speaker, who is alive, and is indicating that something dead becoming alive moves closer to the speaker (it "comes" to the speaker); whereas something alive becoming dead moves away from the speaker (it "goes" away from the speaker). You go insane, but you come to your senses. You come online, but you go offline. Note also that when something "comes down" or "goes down", it suggests different relative positions for the speaker.

@Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' "and multiple things don't *come separated" However, things do come apart.

@Mohir: In my version of English, plans and ideas can happily come together. But things like dips and meals can't - they can only be put together.

@FumbleFingers While I agree that ‘the dip comes together in a jiffy’ doesn’t sound quite right, I have no problem with ‘the dip is coming together nicely’. But then that seems to me to be the same kind of metaphor as plans and ideas: a process that has a final goal getting closer. It definitely feels like a different use/metaphor than ‘comes together in a jiffy’, which doesn’t relate to processes or goals.

"I'm dubious about "come separated", and none of "come shattered", "come split", "come divided", "come isolated" will work." I think what the ones that do work have in common, that these don't, is the implication that not only could the thing could be put back together again, but it's in fact designed to be taken apart and put back together repeatedly. Hence, "unfastened" - not "detached".

@JanusBahsJacquet: I didn't think of it like that earlier, but yeah - that sounds right. Dips coming together quickly or effortlessly don't really work, but foods that need to be prepared can definitely be coming together (or along) nicely, just like plans.

...if something can't be shaping up as it approaches completion / fruition, it probably can't be coming together either. And whereas things can be shaping up nicely, nothing ever shapes up in a jiffy.

In many of these examples, "come" seems to be a shortening of "become."

English, like many other languages, has two “basic” verbs to indicate movement: “come” and “go”. The verb “come” is generally used for motion towards some reference point, and the verb “go” for motion away from some reference point.
English also uses the verbs “come” and “go” for some changes of state. There, the opposition is: things come alive but go dead. The verb “come” can be used in many expressions where something becomes able to move: “come free”, “come alive”, “come loose”, “come unzipped”, etc. Conversely, a room can “go quiet”, a fizzy drink can “go flat”, etc.
Sometimes the same adjective can be used with both verbs, but with a different meaning. For example: “the turban came unwound” — the turban is now flapping in the wind. But “the clock went unwound” — the clock is no longer working.
The expression “come open” is uncommon, but “one of the vessels came open” works because the cover of the vessel becomes able to move, and it becomes possible for things to move in and out of the vessel. Conversely, “go closed” is uncommon but possible, when there is a connotation that “closed” prevents activity.
Etymologically, these uses of “come” date from a time when “come” was a synonym of “become”. I think there has been some influence from the “go near” meaning, so most of the uses of “come + adjective” in modern English are those where something becomes more alive. But the boundaries are subtle. For example, “come apart” is a common expression: you can say “it came apart” to mean that something is broken into multiple pieces, even though you can't say that it “*came broken” or “*came split” or “*came shattered”. The expression “come undone” is most often used metaphorically, as in “his plans came undone”, which means that the plans failed — that metaphorical use is more associated with deadness, but the expression is acceptable because the literal meaning of “come undone” means that something has become more able to move. There are also expressions that don't fit that pattern at all, such as “come true” (a prediction comes true if the thing happens).

"Come" works with many prepositions to form phrases that might be hard to explain but are common. Can mean "happens" ("conception comes before birth") or "be somewhere" ("come before a judge") or refer to intellectual motion ("come to an agreement") . "Come" is fascinatingly useful and somewhat idiomatic in English. Come on! Come here! Come undone. Come together. Come again? Come what may. Come in first. Come away with me.

@user8356 Sure, “come” is a very versatile verb. But that's off-topic here. We're not trying to write the whole dictionary entry for ”come“, we're trying to explain one specific usage of it.

Sorry if I strayed off topic. It seems there is not an easy answer to the question "can come + adjective be used with any adjective" (if I understand the question correctly). It's a bit confusing because "open" and "loose" (mentioned in the question) can be adjectives but are seeming being used as verbs in the "come +" constructions. I would say many adjectives would make no sense with "come" -- "come pretty", "come large", "come tall", for example.
